# Load relation as boolean in Eloquent Collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a classroom model with a hasMany students relationship. I want to check if every classroom has students in one query with eloquent builder. I dont want to retireve the student count either. The has function filters the classrooms that doesn't have students:

```
//Classroom model

class Classroom extends Model
{
    public function students(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
    }
}
```

Tried with:

```
Classroom::has('students')->get();
```

But it only returns the models with students, not what I want. Expected result:

```
[
    {
        "has_students": false
    },
    {
        "has_students": false
    },
    {
        "has_students": true
    },
    {
        "has_students": true
    },
    {
        "has_students": false
    }
]
```

Comment: Use `withCount('students')` and|or create ClassroomResource and add has_students bool value in toArray() method

Comment: @InDevX I dont want to count the students

Comment: U wan't it or not but it is needed for has_students

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a follow up to Amade's answer, we now have a `withExists` method for just checking existence of relationships. So you should be able to do something like this:

```
Classroom::withExists('students')->get();
```

Then, each `Classroom` object will have a property (attribute) named `students_exists` (I believe based on the documentation). You could alias this to `has_students` if you would like:

```
Classroom::withExists('students as has_students')->get();
```

I have not tested this, but based on the documentation this should be what you are looking for.

If you want that specific structure of data returned you can do what Amade demonstrated with the `mapWithKeys` method or use a transformer (API Resource).

[Laravel 10.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Other Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions) - `withExists`

Comment: Nope. The response was just a mock up for clarification. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with:

```
App\Models\Classroom::withCount('students')->get()->mapWithKeys(fn ($classroom) => [$classroom->id => ['has_studends' => $classroom->studends_count > 0]]);
```

That is, use Eqloquent to join classrooms table with the count of students in each classroom, and then map the results with your condition.

Comment: I dont want to load the count of students either, just want to check their existence

Comment: @ManuelGuzman
You don't need to load it, it's just a query optimization.  You could rewrite it as:
App\Models\Classroom::get()->mapWithKeys(fn ($classroom) => [$classroom->id => ['has_studends' => $classroom->studends->isNotEmpty() ]]);

Answer (score 1):

Try adding has_stuents attribute [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;
...

protected function hasStudents(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn ($value) => $this->students->count > 0;
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "hasStudents" method to the Classroom model that uses the "exists" method to check if there are any students associated with the class. Here's an example code to do that:

```
class Classroom extends Model
{
    public function students(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
    }

    public function hasStudents(): bool
    {
        return $this->students()->exists();
    }
}
```

Then, to get the array of objects with the "has_students" property that indicates whether each class has students, you can run a query to retrieve all classrooms and use the "map" method to create the desired array:

```
$classrooms = Classroom::all();
$classroomData = $classrooms->map(function ($classroom) {
    return [
        'has_students' => $classroom->hasStudents()
    ];
});
```

Finally, you can convert $classroomData to JSON using the "toJson" method:

```
$jsonData = $classroomData->toJson();
```

This will produce the desired JSON array with the "has_students" property for each class.

Comment: With that, you're creating an N+1 problem, since you have to query the existence in every model, instead of preloading it for all of them.